# SwiftUI List scrollbar resizes as it scrolls

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a simple view with a list of custom views. The list appears after loading from an API with the following code:

```swift
List(viewModel.repositories) { repository in
 SetupRepositoryView(repository)
}
```

As I scroll, the scrollbar resizes. I think this is something to do with SwiftUI lazily loading the content. Is there any way to refresh the scrollbar view at the start.

[image: SwiftUI list scrollbar resizing]

Comment: try by providing minimum height on cell

Comment: What's your SDK and your test OS version? I have seen this behaving "lazy" in 10.15 and fine in 10.12 with the identical builds.